# Go and Bazel: Using external Git repositories

Tags: git, go, bazel

Thus far, I have been using `go` tool to fetch dependencies. I've set `$GOPATH` to `~/projects/holygrail`, and I've checked out my code into `src/mycodehosting.foo/myuser/holygrail`.

Given that I actually depend on things such as gRPC, which means I need to build `protoc` from protobuf v3's source, I've written a small script that helps me do this. I would strongly prefer to *not* have to pre-prepare layout when I check out my source code, and I would strongly prefer *not* to use a bash script to fetch my dependencies, and then build them.

Current tentative solution:

- use Git submodules to fetch external dependencies (which, sadly, means no smart redirects that `go get` knows how to do)
- use Go 1.5's vendoring by flipping the `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT` variable to 1
- switch to Bazel to have a sane build system which will know how to build various dependencies only as required

Unfortunately, I am *slightly* stuck.

- I'm using Bazel 0.1.1 with Skylark rules for Go from git repo copied into `~/.bazel/base_workspace`
- I originally tried using `new_local_repository` (later to be switched to use `new_git_repository`) inside Bazel's `WORKSPACE`, specifying a custom `BUILD` file for one of the dependencies

  - this broke down because Bazel was unable to find the Go Skylark rules
- I am not sure how would I write custom `BUILD`-files for `git-submodule`-downloaded repositories in `vendor/` folder, and expose them to Bazel.

---

Am I on the right track? Am I correct to use submodules? Am I correct to use `vendor/` subfolder to store Go libraries?

- **What is the recommended way to build external dependencies using Bazel, where both the code and the dependencies are written in Go?**
- Could you provide an example of a repository that:

  - correctly depends on an external `BUILD`-file-less Go repository (without actually importing the upstream code)?
  - correctly builds the Go code in the external repository?
  - correctly integrates the Go code from the external repository into the main Go project?

---

Some more research into this:

- Kythe seems to have one `BUILD` file for many dependencies (even though they are not submodules, that does not make a difference).

  - Here is their [BUILD file](https://github.com/google/kythe/blob/master/third_party/go/BUILD)
  - Here is their [additional helper rule](https://github.com/google/kythe/blob/master/third_party/go/build.bzl)
- That helper rule uses the `go_package()` rule. But this seems to come [from Kythe itself](https://github.com/google/kythe/blob/master/tools/build_rules/go.bzl).

  - It doesn't seem right to start using rules from Kythe, but it seems like a possible way to go?
  - What do other people do?

Answer (score 0):

As of few versions ago, Bazel supports slashes in rule names. Along with hacked-in support for custom package names (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/16) this seems to cover my use case.

tl;dr I have `//vendor:BUILD` file which has rules such as `go_library(name='github.com/blah/blah', ...)`. Directories are named, e.g., `//vendor/github.com/blah/blah`. Each subpackage has a separate rule. I've manually specified dependencies.